# File upload fails laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

so I created simple form to upload files and dd the $request->file

```
<form 
    action="/videos" 
    method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    id="upload_form"
    name="upload_form"
    >
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="avatar" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

`dd($request->file('avatar');`

if the video is above 1 mb but less than 8 mb it get's uploaded with error 1 and a size of 0 mb if the video is above 8 mb I get an error
`Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException`
`PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 21712952 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

this is my php.ini file inside laravel

```
post_max_size = 100M
; upload_max_filesize = 60M
variables_order = EGPCS
max_execution_time = 3600s
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 60M
```

Comment: do you want to return the picture

Comment: Did you check with `phpinfo()` if the .ini file is taking effect?

Comment: No I'm just debugging

Answer (score 1):

Your php.ini config is fine. The problem is in the nginx config.

You must increase the `client_max_body_size`. The default value of it is `1 MB` per file.

Add the following in your `default.conf` of your nginx project:

```
server {
    ...

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I still got the same errors

Comment: as someone commented I tried to see if it my php.ini is taking effect but actualy it isn't and i try to restart nginx i got an erro